# how to parse text with enter in xml in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to parse some text from a xml. But text contains enter so now whenever i try to read, it does not read beyond enter. 
Can some one help me? I really stuck.

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this.

```
NSString *xmlString = //the xml data;
[xmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\0" withString:@""];

//Now you can parse the xmlString
```

Hope it helped....